# What exactly happens when a qualifier is added to a layout or values?

Tags: java, android

Something that has been bothering me in android is when I create a layout I have an option to add qualifier. For instance, when I add a layout I have the option to put in the qualifier of orientation and landscape or portrait.

1) What confuses me is how does android exactly knows which layouts files to use simply by adding a qualifier?

2) What code keeps track of this resource and called when appropriate because a resource can't just simply determine which files to be drawn from but rather there has to be a code saying which resource to load much like setContentView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android chooses the appropriate layout file based on (a) the physical characteristics of the device, e.g. screen density, and (b) the state of the device, e.g. orientation.

For example, if your phone is high-density, the layout in res/layout-hdpi will be used (if it exists).

Or if your phone is in landscape mode, the layout in res/layout-land will be used (if it exists).

For more info see: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

When a layout is inflated those properties are read and used. No one keeps track of them other the developer.

Comment: But if a layout is inflated like that how exactly does android knows to called which layout to be use?

Comment: There are some default values and some required ones. Android "knows" all the default values. You need to override the default ones, if needed, and provide the required ones or you get an errors.